# What's the best practice of the On-demand parachains in 2024?

Tags: parachain, parathread, coretime

Before the Coretime, the only choice for the on-demand parachain is parathread (please correct me if I am wrong), there is a discussion https://forum.polkadot.network/t/on-demand-parachains/2208 and the related code has been merged.  Then, comes the Coretime, the parachain has more options to buy a bulk coretime or just some regions. It seems that for the parachain that wants to be on-demand, it doesn't need to be a parathread anymore, just buy some coretime when when there are transactions.

So, my question is:

1. What's the best practice of the on-demand for parachains in the Coretime era?
2. What's going on the already merged parathread, does it have other use cases?
3. From the Bastian's tweet https://twitter.com/bkchr/status/1738306372708544662, it seems the Coretime has been running on the Rococo, but I haven't found the corresponding pallet, such as `pallet_broker`, anything that I'm missing?

Comment: 3. `pallet-broker` is in `Coretime` system parachain of `Rococo` https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-coretime-rpc.polkadot.io#/rpc